Nginx + Fastcgi - adding a timeout for a specific route
I have a PHP Symfony application behind nginx/php-fpm - I would like to add a fastcgi timeout, but only for a specific endpoint. Here is what I tried.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location /foo/bar {
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 1s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 1s;

        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location / {
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            return 204;
        }

        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}

Unfortunately while the config loads correctly, the request does not timeout after 1 second as expected - the timeout value does not seem to carry over to location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$). However in that block I also cannot put the timeout behind a condition because "fastcgi_read_timeout" directive is not allowed here.
How can adding a timeout for a specific endpoint be achieved in this configuration?

You can use nested locations:

location blocks can be nested, with some exceptions mentioned below.

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    internal;

    location /foo/bar {
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 1s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 1s;
    }
}

Without nesting only the location that matches best will be used, in the order explained in the documentation:

To find location matching a given request, nginx first checks locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations). Among them, the location with the longest matching prefix is selected and remembered. Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance in the configuration file. The search of regular expressions terminates on the first match, and the corresponding configuration is used. If no match with a regular expression is found then the configuration of the prefix location remembered earlier is used.


The config is not valid with the change  nginx: [emerg] location "/v1/transportation-plan/delivery-options/pickup-locations" is outside location "^/index\.php(/|$)" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:42 I could make it replacing the location pattern with a regex but it never matches.
